# Reading a specific row & columns of data in a text file using Python 2.7

Tags: python

I am new to Python and need to extract data from a text file.  I have a text file below:

```
UNHOLTZ-DICKIE CORPORATION
CALIBRATION DATA
789     3456
222     455
333     5
344     67788
12      6789
2456    56656
```

And I want to read it on the shell as two columns of data only:

```
789     3456
222     455
333     5
344     67788
12      6789
2456    56656
```

Comment: [Best-guess formatting edits; please revise if necessary.]

Comment: It's pretty hard to know exactly what you want from your (single) example. Here are some options: break the line at spaces, take only the pieces that are numbers; find 'CALIBRATION DATA' as a literal, take the rest of the line after that; or something else. You know the data; what will work to parse it? (The more complex the 'rules' for parsing the data, the harder it will be to write code...)

Comment: What part of string slicing is confusing to you?  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html contains a description of string slicing.  Isn't this what you're doing?  Can you explain what part of the slice notation section is difficult or confusing?

Comment: What is the destination of the data?

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions.  The output data shall be only two columns of data appended on a new text file (destination not important).  The columns will be separated by a Tab space.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python program that reads a file and outputs the 3rd... lines (drops the first 2 lines). That's all I can deduce that you want given your short explanation.

```
# read the whole file
file = open("input.file", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

# Skip first 2 lines, output the rest to stdout
count = 0
for line in lines:
    count +=1
    if count > 2:
         print line,
```

Comment: Thanks Art this is what I'm looking for.  I have no experience in software so this helps alot.

Comment: It's considered good form to vote for the answer that solves your need. (You vote by clicking on the checkmark.) To get the most out of SO, I'd recommend reading the frequently asked questions; the link is at the very top of the page: "faq".

Answer (score 0):

If you have numpy installed then this is a one-liner:

```
   col1,col2 = numpy.genfromtxt("myfile.txt",skiprows=2,unpack=True)
```

where myfile.txt is your data file.

Comment: I don't have numpy.  I have 2.7.2 so I guess the numpy module is in a later version?

Comment: If you are planning on doing any sort of number crunching or general scientific computing with python then numpy is the most useful thing to have.